# Android Wear OS

Tags: android, compilation, wear-os, watch, signed

Select 'pair with Empty phone app' as Wear os and create a project.

However, the following error occurs during 'Generate Signed Buddle'.

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:

:wear:compileReleaseArtProfile

\--- :wear:mergeDexRelease

     \--- :wear:dexBuilderRelease

          +--- :wear:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

          |    +--- :wear:compileReleaseKotlin

          |    |    +--- :wear:dataBindingGenBaseClassesRelease

          |    |    |    +--- :wear:mergeReleaseResources
          |    |    |    |    \--- :wear:generateReleaseResources
          |    |    |    |         \--- :wear:handleReleaseMicroApk
          |    |    |    |              \--- :wear:packageRelease
         
.
.
.
.

          |    |    \--- :wear:processReleaseResources (*)

          |    +--- :wear:dataBindingGenBaseClassesRelease (*)

          |    \--- :wear:processReleaseResources (*)

          +--- :wear:compileReleaseKotlin (*)

          \--- :wear:processReleaseResources (*)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the error log you receive?

Comment: and maybe the contents of the other 2 build.gradle files

Answer (score 4):

Error happened to me, needed to delete `wearApp project(":wear")` dependency from wear `build.gradle`